# How to assign a Future variable to a class getter in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, future

I'm trying to read user data from Firebase via Streamer and assign them into properties of my User class. I have a FirabaseActions class doing firebase stuff. Here is the method that I use streamer to get data. It works perfectly, and print(user.data['userName']); give me the right result.

```
static Future<User> userDataStream(loggedInUserEmail) async {
    final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;
    User currentUser;

    await for (var snapshot in databaseReference
        .collection('users')
        .where('email', isEqualTo: loggedInUserEmail)
        .snapshots()) {
      for (var user in snapshot.documents) {
        print(user.data['userName']);
        currentUser.userName = user.data['userName'];
        currentUser.email = user.data['email'];
        currentUser.userID = user.data['userID'];
        currentUser.level = user.data['level'];
      }
    }
    return currentUser;
  }
```

The problem begin when I try to assign these user info to my class properties. Here is my User class. I got an error like below. It is about Future type but I can't handle it. What should I do?

Class 'Future' has no instance getter 'email'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Future'
Tried calling: email

```
class User {
  String userName;
  String userID;
  String email;
  int level;

  User({this.userName, this.userID, this.level, this.email});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you cant assign an username like this

`currentUser.userName = user.data['userName'];`
 Because currentUser is null. A simple solution to that is to replace
 `User currentUser;` with `User currentUser = User();`

Second problem :

I think you should never search user by his email, rather by the UID that you get from

`FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()`,

So you would query for the user like this :

```
  static Future<User> userDataStream() async {
    final firestore = Firestore.instance;
    final currentFirestoreUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    User currentUser;

    var query = await firestore
        .collection('users')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: currentFirestoreUser.uid)
        .getDocuments();
    var user = query.documents.first.data;
    currentUser = User(
        userName: user['userName'],
        userID: user['userID'],
        level: user['level'],
        email: user['email']);

    return currentUser;
  }
```

You could add UID as a method's parameter, or leave it inside the method.

Comment: User currentUser = User(); solves my issue. But I still get the same error when I try to reach currentUser.email from another class. For example; I call this method from my Home Screen such as  onPressed: () {
                            dynamic user = FirebaseActions.userDataStream(
                                loggedInUser.email);
                            print(user.email);
                            });
                          }, But again I got the same error Class 'Future<User>' has no instance getter 'email'.